# Find unquoted strings and quote them using regex

Tags: php, preg-match

I've got a website in front of me that contains 2500 session variables, most of which are labeled WITHOUT quotes (not my work obviously....).
For example

```
$_SESSION[var]
```

rather than

```
$_SESSION['var']
```

Now, I've got to change all 2500 of them to make sure they have quotes. I know I'm going to have to write some PHP to loop through every file and check every session variable. I would probably use preg_match but I'm not sure of the regular expression I need. When i've found the ones without a quote, I'm going to have to to a str_replace , unless someone can think of a better method?

Anyone know of it? Can't do this manually, it may kill me! :) cheers

Comment: With some code editors, like PSPad, You can perform search/replace on files within a path, recursively. Then searching for `[(.*)]` and replacing with `['$1']` would not be a problem.

Comment: Hey @shadyyx - PSPad would be a good solution, although I am stuck on a Mach here..

Comment: If on Mac, why not using command line? Like this [example](http://lifehacker.com/5810026/quickly-find-and-replace-text-across-multiple-documents-via-the-command-line).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$yourCodeWhereYouNeedToReplace = file_get_contents('awfulCode.php'); //:P
preg_replace_callback('/_SESSION\[(\w+)\]/',
                      function ($matches)
                      { return '_SESSION[\''.$matches[1].'\']'; },
                      $yourCodeWhereYouNeedToReplace);
```

**Edit:** You can also use pattern `\[(\w+)\]` if you want to replace all `[key]` with `['key']`.

Comment: @SalmanA Regex won't match it so it won't be replaced since it's valid. Or do you mean `$_SESSION['key1']['key2']`?

Comment: LOL! Love the 'awfulCode.php' - it really is awful code. But this is part of the life of being a developer, picking up other peoples rubbish ;)

Comment: @30secondstosam Yeah, we can do nothing with that. Will be glad if this helps you. :)

Comment: @PLB hi PLB - so are you saying that if i used something like : preg_replace('\[(\w+)\]/', '\[(\w+)\]', $match) , that would replace all the [key] with ['key']?

Comment: @30secondstosam If you use `preg_replace('/\[(\w+)\]/', '[\'$1\']', $match);` will replace all  [key] with ['key'].